# Google Analytics funnel not receiving any entrances

Tags: google-analytics

I have a goal funnel built in Google Analytics and the first step is required. Since setting up the funnel, that first step page is receiving pageviews, but the funnel remains empty, no one has entered. It's only been about 18 hours since I updated the funnel.

Why would the first step be receiving pageviews (in a Site Content report), but the Funnel Visualization report is showing 0 entrances? Wouldn't the Funnel Visualization report show entrances even if no one actually successfully completed the funnel? Does the Funnel Visualization report update slower than a regular Site Content report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. The destination used regular expression as the matching criteria, but the first step of the funnel contained a "?" that was not escaped and therefore wasn't correctly capturing visitors in the first step of the funnel.

I pieced together the resolution in Google's documentation here in the Tips for Setting up Funnels section at the bottom: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en